# Cannot set a property "year" of undefined TypeScript-Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following declaration in my component:

```
private years: Array<{
    year: string,
    colspan: number
  }> = [];
```

Which is supposed to be a `years`-Array where each entry has the two properties `year` and `colspan`. Now I want to modify this variable with the following method called in my `ngOnInit`:

```
fillYearsArray = () => {
    var currentIndex : number = 1;
    //fill the first entry and do not change it afterwards, error occurs here
    this.years[0].year = "";
    this.years[0].colspan= 1;

    this.items.forEach( (item) => {
      //if the first entry.year is empty fill it with the year of the current object
      if (this.years[currentIndex].year) {
      //if it is already set and the years equal enlarge colspan  
      //otherwise go to the next entry with the "new" year
      if (this.years[currentIndex].year === String(item.year)) {
          this.years[currentIndex].colspan += this.columnKeys.length;
        } else {
          currentIndex++;
          this.years[currentIndex].year = String(item.year);
          this.years[currentIndex].colspan = this.columnKeys.length;
        }
      } else {
        this.years[currentIndex].year = String(item.year);
      }
    });
  }
```

But when running `ng serve` I get the following output:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'year' of undefined
    at TabularComponent.fillYearsArray (tabular.component.ts:27)
    at TabularComponent.push../src/app/tabular/tabular.component.ts.TabularComponent.ngOnInit (tabular.component.ts:22)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18537)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19801)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19763)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20397)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20357)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20349)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19745)
```

So it looks like the first object in the array would be undefined, but shouldn't TS know, that it has an property `year` that is changed for the object at the first entry of my `years`-array?

Comment: Is your years array set before you go in your function, if not you need to push data into it before doing this.year[0]

Comment: ```this.years[0] = {
      year: "",
      colspan: 1
    }```

Comment: do it like this this.year.push( { year: "", colspan: 1 }) and like that it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an element before you change it's value

you try to access

```
this.years[0]
```

but this.years length is 0

so you need to do it like this

```
this.years.push({ year: "", colspan: 1});
```

if you want to add item in your array you need to use the .push() function.
If you try to go to the index you want to set, it won't work